# Mapsui MapView blank in .Net Maui

Tags: c#, maui-blazor, mapsui

I have a strange issue.
I want to Create a ContentView with a Mapsui MapView in it.
But when I do this, the MapView is displayed but it is blank.

[image]

This is obviously wrong.

Here is a simple version of the issue:

**MapView.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mapsui="clr-namespace:Mapsui.UI.Maui;assembly=Mapsui.UI.Maui"
             x:Class="MauiApp7.Pages.MapView">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Text="Get Location" Grid.Row="0" Clicked="GetLocationAsync" ></Button>
        <mapsui:MapView x:Name="_mapView"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    BackgroundColor="Gray" 
                        Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

**MapView.xaml.cs**

```
using Mapsui.UI.Maui;
using MauiApp7.Pages.ViewModels;

namespace MauiApp7.Pages;


public partial class MapView : ContentView
{
    public MapViewModel ViewModel => BindingContext as MapViewModel;

    public MapView()
    {
        BindingContext = ServiceProvider.GetService<MapViewModel>();
        _mapView = new Mapsui.UI.Maui.MapView();
        _mapView.Map.Layers.Add(Mapsui.Tiling.OpenStreetMap.CreateTileLayer());
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }
    private async void GetLocationAsync(object sender, EventArgs EventArgs)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Then, to simplify things, I just set the content in MainPage to a map view:
**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var map = new Pages.MapView();
        Content = map;
    }
}
```

I can't understand why this is.

If I set the MainPage.xaml.cs content directly to a

```
Mapsui.UI.Maui.MapView();
```

then that works.
Like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var mapView = new Mapsui.UI.Maui.MapView();
        mapView.Map?.Layers.Add(Mapsui.Tiling.OpenStreetMap.CreateTileLayer());
        Content = mapView;
    }
}
```

then I get my map correctly displayed.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the code of `MapViewModel `, `Mapsui.UI.Maui.MapView`? Could you please post more code snippets or a basic demo so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

Comment: @njun, have you located a solution? I am also running into this issue as I am using the MVVM pattern and  no changes propigate when I perform any changes to MapView in the ViewModel.  It works fine if I embed everything into the xaml code-behind but woud like to use MVVM.

Comment: @Derek, Sorry, for the late reply. I had to put this project on hold due to time constraints. I hope to get back to it one day but for now I don't have a solution. If you do manage, it would be great to see your code.

Comment: All good @njun, I did a workaround, in my code behind for xaml, I have a call to my ViewModel (on On appearing), I am sending MapView as a parameter, then using as needed after that, not ideal, but works. If more needs to be passed due to lack of MVVM support it'll get out of hand, but fine for one property.